# Extraer datos de un comando con Powershell

Tags: batch, powershell

Dado el comando "tasklist /fi "username eq xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxxxx"" este devuelve lo siguiente:

```
Nombre de imagen               PID Nombre de sesión Núm. de ses Uso de memor
========================= ======== ================ =========== ============
vmwp.exe                      6687 Services                   0    24.152 KB
```

Necesito extraer el PID del proceso para meterlo en una variable, matar el dicho proceso y poder reiniciarlo en un script.

Comment: Hola., me parece que son varias preguntas en una, revisar [ask], saludos

Comment: Más concretamente, en un script, como cojo la el PID del output de ese comando y meterlo en una variable para trabajar con el.

Comment: El resultado de Get-Process es una colección de objetos de tipo Process.  Es fácil pedir el nombre de usuario si eres adminitrador.  Es también fácil extraer el Id.  
[Help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-process?view=powershell-7.3)

Answer (score 0):

Para extraer el PID del proceso utilizando el comando tasklist, puedes utilizar un script en PowerShell. Aquí te dejo un ejemplo de cómo hacerlo:

```
$processInfo = tasklist /fi "username eq xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxxxx" /fo csv | ConvertFrom-Csv
if ($processInfo) {
    $pid = $processInfo.PID
    Write-Host "PID del proceso: $pid"
    Stop-Process -Id $pid -Force
    Start-Process "ruta\del\proceso.exe"
    Write-Host "Proceso reiniciado."
} else {
    Write-Host "El proceso no está en ejecución."
}
```

Este script de PowerShell realiza los siguientes pasos:

1. Obtiene la información del proceso mediante el comando tasklist.
2. Convierte la salida del comando en un formato que PowerShell pueda manejar `ConvertFrom-Csv`
3. Verifica si la información del proceso está disponible.
4. Si el proceso está en ejecución, extrae el PID y lo almacena en la variable `$pid`
5. Muestra el PID del proceso.
6. Detiene el proceso con el comando `Stop-Process`
7. Reinicia el proceso (ajusta la ruta y el nombre del proceso según tus necesidades).
8. Muestra un mensaje indicando que el proceso ha sido reiniciado.

Asegúrate de ejecutar este script con privilegios elevados para que tenga permisos para detener y reiniciar procesos. También, ten en cuenta que deberás ajustar la ruta y el nombre del proceso según tus necesidades específicas.